# How mock ActionContext with Moq aspnetcore C# xUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I am trying mock this controller:

```
public IActionResult List()
{          

   Response.Headers.Add("contentRange", "1");
   Response.Headers.Add("acceptRange", "1");

   return Ok();
}
```

With this test:

```
[Fact]
public void when_call_list_should_return_sucess()
{
   //Arrange

   //Act
   var result = _purchaseController.List();

   //Assert
   Assert.Equal(200, ((ObjectResult)result).StatusCode);
}
```

But my HttpContext is null, and an error occurs, how could I mock my ActionContext and HttpContext to test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this where you construct your _purchaseController, in your Setup or the like. In your case you don't even have to mock it.

```
_purchaseController = new PurchaseController
{
    ControllerContext = new ControllerContext 
    {
        HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext()
    }
}
```

But if you also want to verify the response headers you would probably mock both the `HttpContext` and the expected `HttpResponse`, and provide your own `HeaderDictionary` to verify.

```
_headers = new HeaderDictionary();

var httpResponseMock = new Mock<HttpResponse>();
httpResponseMock.Setup(mock => mock.Headers).Returns(_headers);

var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContext>();
httpContextMock.Setup(mock => mock.Response).Returns(httpResponseMock.Object);

_purchaseController = new PurchaseController
{
    ControllerContext = new ControllerContext 
    {
        HttpContext = httpContextMock.Object
    }
}
```

Then you could Assert the header collection in a test

```
var result = _sut.List();

Assert.Equal("1", _headers["contentRange"]);
Assert.Equal("1", _headers["acceptRange"]);
```